# How to split string arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, split

Here is the code

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np

arr = ["unit","2","3","4","5","6"]
print("Original arr: ", arr)
np.random.shuffle(arr)
print("Shuffled arr: ", arr)
kfj=input()
newarr = np.split(arr,2)
```

When I run this I get this error:

```
N = ary.shape[axis]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

How can I split that string array? Also I have to make it random so I shuffled it.

Comment: since it seems like you are more familiar with numpy, you can just convert it to a numpy array.  `arr = np.array(arr)`  Otherwise you can split the list using slices just like you can in numpy `arr1 = arr[:len(arr)/2]`, `arr2 = arr[len(arr)/2:]`

Comment: I can't understand. What should it mean to "split" the list (it is **not an "array"**) of strings? What should the result look like, and why?